# Generate a truth table of arbitrary length haskell

Tags: haskell, combinations, permutation

for an assignment I have to generate a truth table like this:

```
combinations :: Int -> [[Bool]]
```

combinations 3 should output:

```
[[False, False, False],[False, False, True],[False, True, False],[False, True, True][True, False, False][True, False, True],[True, True, False],[True, True, True]]
```

I can do a list comprehension:

```
combinations n = [[a,b] | a<-[True,  False], b <-[True, False]]
```

but that doesn't scale for arbitrary numbers.

Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: There is the `replicateM` function in the `Control.Monad` module for generating combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to @chi 's answer, here's a recursive way of implementing the function. I've renamed it to a snappier `truths`:

```
truths :: Int -> [[Bool]]
truths 0 = [[]]
truths n = do
    b <- [True,False]
    map (b :) (truths (n - 1))
```

those last 3 lines could be rewritten as

```
truths n = [True,False] >>= \b -> map (b :) (truths (n - 1))
```

Here we simply append a true/false value to each element in the previous result. The only edge case would be for negative numbers, but you can probably work that out yourself.

I tried this solution out in GHCi, it computes `truths 10` in about 0.6 seconds, which is impressive, considering there are 1024 lists, each containing 10 elements.

I also came up with another, more interesting version using `sequence` from `Control.Monad`:

```
import Control.Monad (sequence)

truths :: Int -> [[Bool]]
truths n = sequence (replicate n [True,False])
```

this will produce the same output. Note that it could also be rewritten in a points-free style as such, to the same effect:

```
truths = sequence . flip replicate [True,False]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should reason recursively.

To generate the `n`-combinations, you can proceed as follows. First, generate all the `n-1`-combinations: name this list `c` (this a list of lists of booleans). Then, for every element `xs` of `c` (here `xs` is a list of booleans), generate `x:xs` where `x` is an arbitrary boolean. Handle the case `n=0` specially, so to provide a base case.