# Haskell combination of number and bool

Tags: haskell, combinations

In Haskell, when I input a list of ordered number, how can I make a list which has all the possible combination of the number and the bool(either True or False) ?

for example
when I input [1,2]
the output is:

```
[ [(1,False),(2,False)]
, [(1,False),(2,True)]
, [(1,True),(2,False)]
, [(1,True), (2,True)] ]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate a truth table of arbitrary length haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27229899/generate-a-truth-table-of-arbitrary-length-haskell)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list monad might be the easiest to understand:

```
f xs = do
    bs <- replicateM (length xs) [False, True]  -- Obtain |xs| elements from the set of all possible booleans
    return (zip xs bs)                          -- Pair the elements of each list
```

With a result of:

```
Prelude Control.Monad> f [1,2]
[[(1,False),(2,False)],[(1,False),(2,True)],[(1,True),(2,False)],[(1,True),(2,True)]]
```

Comment: Or: `f = mapM (\x -> [(x, False), (x, True)])`.

Answer (score 2):

```
b1 n = sequence $ replicate n [False,True]

b2 xs = map (zip xs) (b1 (length xs))
```

Example:

```
*Main> b2 [1,2]
[[(1,False),(2,False)],[(1,False),(2,True)],[(1,True),(2,False)],[(1,True),(2,True)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

with list comprehensions

```
[zip [1..] [x,y] | x<-[True,False], y<-[True,False]]
```